Forgot green card at home and traveled by aircraft to Mexico
I am traveling from the US to Mexico. I have forgotten my green card but I have my REAL ID,passport,and expired visa. Will I be permitted to come back to the US by aircraft with those documents?

What country issued your passport? If not a visa-waiver country, you could easily have a trusted friend in the US send the Green Court to you via courier such as DHL, FedEx, or similar.

It was issued by Mexico

Was the expired visa an immigrant visa? If so, how long ago was your entry on the immigrant visa?


Will I be permitted to come back to the US by aircraft with those documents?

Unlikely.
You'll probably be denied boarding before ever reaching the CBP officers. There's an option for an airline to ask for a permission to let you board without the documents, but they don't have to do that. You'll need to either have someone mail the card to you or go to a US consulate and ask for a foil.
You can try and walk across the border and explain yourself directly to the CBP officers. That might not work either.
See the list of options here.

The transportation boarding foil looks like an option, but… $575 for a one-time use! I suppose getting someone to overnight it will be a lot cheaper and simpler.

It's for the case of a loss, obviously :) overnighting seems like the most sensible solution.

@jcaron that's because it's for dire emergencies only. And the cost would probably be partially or fully waved in such cases (or covered by travel insurance). Think stolen travel documents while abroad. The high fee is designed to deter people using the service just because they forgot their documents at home.
